# Is this inequality true? $ (nk)! \ge n^k \cdot k! $

Tags: combinatorics, factorial

> Is this inequality true?
>   $$ (nk)! \ge n^k \cdot k! $$

I fixed a $k$ and tried a few values of $n$, and it seems to be true. But when trying to prove it by induction on $n$, I am not getting anywhere.

Bases case $n=1$ is true with equality. Assume it is true for some $n$, i.e. $ (nk)! \ge n^k \cdot k! $ is true. Now we need to show $ ((n+1)k)! \ge (n+1)^k \cdot k!$

$$ \left( \left( n+1 \right)k \right)!=\left( nk+k \right)!=\left( nk \right)!k!\left( \begin{matrix}
   nk+k  \\
   k  \\
\end{matrix} \right)\ge {{n}^{k}}{{\left( k! \right)}^{2}}\left( \begin{matrix}
   nk+k  \\
   k  \\
\end{matrix} \right) $$

But this gets me nowhere since I need a $n+1$ to appear after the inequality. Suggestions? I guess there must be an easier non-induction proof.

Comment: Have you tried induction on $k$?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$$ (nk)!=1\cdot 2\cdot\ldots\cdot nk= \ldots\cdot n\cdot \ldots\cdot2n\cdot \ldots\cdot 3n\cdot \ldots\cdot kn\ge k!n^k $$

Answer (score 4):

The symmetric group $S_{nk}$ has
$$\frac{(nk)!}{n^k k!}$$
elements consisting of $k$ cycles of length $n$. So not only $n^kk!\le(nk)!$, but $n^kk!\mid(nk)!$.

Comment: Can you tell what that last line is? I don't understand the operation/relation the pipe symbol is meant to convey.

Comment: The symbol means "divides" in this context.

Comment: Note that this can also be generalized to $(n!)^k k! \mid (nk)!$.